Positive integral solutions to $a^3+b^3+1=a^2b^2$
$$a^3+b^3+1=a^2b^2$$
This is what I tried:
$(a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab)=(ab-1)(ab+1)$
I compared the two, getting $(a-b)^2=1$, a=b+1 or b-1, since equation is symmetric, $a>=b$ so a=b+1 only.
But later realised that this approach has a flaw since we can't compare just like that.
So, I tried checking for gcd of (ab-1 , ab+1) -> 1 or 2 by euclid division algorithm.
I tried making odd even cases but it didn't yield.
Is there any way I can approach it from here. Also, if you approach it in a different way altogether, what was the thought process.

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that
$$a^3+b^3+1=a^2b^2.$$
First note that if $a=b$ then $2a^3+1=a^4$, which cleary has no integral solutions, so without loss of generality $a<b$. Next note that the equation is equivalent to
$$(b-a^2)b^2+a^3+1=0,$$
which immediately shows that $b<a^2$, because $a$ and $b$ are both positive. Similarly, we also have
$$a^2(b^2-a)=b^3+1=(b+1)(b^2-b+1)$$
Because $a<b$ we have $b^2-a\geq b^2-b+1$, and so we see that $a^2\leq b+1$. It follows that we have equality, and plugging  $b=a^2-1$ into the original equation yields
$$a^3+(a^2-1)^3+1=a^2(a^2-1)^2.$$
Expanding both sides and simplifying yields $a^2-a-2=0$ and so we find that $a=2$.
This shows that the only positive integral solutions are $(a,b)=(2,3)$ and $(a,b)=(3,2)$.

Hey, found your solution the best but,
can you let me know if this approach I just thought is right?
considering a<=b, and calculate the value of a, at a=b, and that would be the max value of a. So we've got the maximum value of the variable with smaller value. and i got it around a=2.15. so we have to check for a=1 and 2 only. Will this approach be correct for subjective exams like IMO. I'm preparing for it and am currently in high school.

If I have understood you correctly, then that is not a sound argument, unfortunately. This is more clear with a simpler equation such as
$$a^2+b^2+1=3ab.$$
It is symmetric in $a$ and $b$, so considering $a\leq b$ you would argue that the maximum value of $a$ is at $a=b$, yielding $a=1$. But $(a,b)=(5,13)$ is another solution, and in fact there are arbitrarily large solutions.

Thank you so much!

Without loss of generality, asssume $a \ge b$. That the LHS grows as $a^3$, which is faster than the RHS which grows as $b^2 a^2$. Thus there is an upper bound for $a$ in terms of $b$, and the growth estimates suggest that bound will be near $b^2$. Indeed, you can easily show the LHS is larger than the RHS for $ a = b^2$, and thus any solution has $a < b^2$. Trying $a = b^2 - 1$ and doing some algebra gives
$$
a^3 + b^3 + 1 - a^2 b^2 = -b^2(b + 1)(b-2),
$$
which immediately gives the solution $a = 3, b= 2$.
On the other hand, this quantity is always negative for $b > 2$, meaning the RHS is larger than the LHS for $a = b^2 - 1$. Since the LHS is larger when $a = b^2$, there is no integer value of $a$ that can make the two equal. So $a =3, b= 2$ is in fact the only solution.

Referring to the statment : LHS grows as a^3 - faster than RHS as a^2b^2. I tried to approach similarly before but I do not think so that LHS growth will be faster. Correct me if I'm wrong but:
LHS is minimum when b = 1, and max at b = a-1 since b=a doesn't yield any solution.
RHS similarly.
$LHS min = a^3 +1$
$RHS min = a^2 -1$
LHS min > RHS min
always.
But, I believe the max case i.e. b=a-1, LHS max < RHS max.

You've shown that $a=b^2-k$ and that the only solution for $k=1$ is with $b=2$. This in no way shows that this is the only solution.....

@MikeBennett A cubic only catches up to a quadratic once.

Huh? There are elliptic curves in Weierstrass form (i.e. as cubic = quadratic) with more than $100$ integral points.

@MikeBennett When talking about the growth rate in my answer, I'm treating $b$ as fixed and looking at how the LHS and RHS vary with $a$. When a cubic and quadratic are both increasing, there is only one point where the quadratic goes from larger to smaller than the cubic.

@eyeballfrog You have a cubic and quadratic in two variables here. You seem to be thinking of the univariate case.

With substitution $s=a+b$, $p=ab$, the given equation rewrites
$$p^2=s^3-3sp+1.$$
One recognizes an elliptic equation, on which obvious integral points are $(s,p)=(0, \pm 1)$, $(-1,0)$, $(-1,3)$, $(5,-21)$, $(5,6)$. According to SageMath, these are all.
Note that due to the symmetry, one can assume without loss of generality $a\le b$.
Thus, the only solution in positive integers to the problem is indeed $(a,b)=(2,3)$.

What is obvious about $(5, -21)$?

#MJD As soon as one insert $s= 5$ in the equation, the adjective `obvious' seems properly used.
